# Global Mute in Windows Phone 8

Tags: 8.0, sound

There's some times I want my Windows Phone to be *completely* silent - disable all ringtones, alert sounds, and app sounds/music. It's easy enough to set the phone to vibrate only for alerts/rings, but I can't find a simple way to mute everything else except to just turn the volume all the way down every time.

It would be *much* simpler and easier if there was a button or app I could use as a mute/unmute function - just like a TV's mute button works - which will totally silence the phone when desired and restore it to its previous volume settings when un-silenced. Is such a feature or app generally available?

Answer (score 7):

Just lower your volume to 0 and everything (except your alarms) will be muted completely. There's only one volume controller in Windows Phone 7 and Windows Phone 8.

Comment: I think this not apply for alarms.

Comment: You would'nt want it to apply for alarms as then you wouldn't be able to hear your alarm.  All things have exceptions.

Comment: Added the exclusion of alarms.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows Phone 8, if you tap the volume button with the phone unlocked, it will bring down the volume / music shade. On this shade, in the upper right hand corner is an icon you can tap to mute / unmute the volume.

NOTE: If it is muted, an alarm will still ring at normal volume. This is so you don't accidently forget it and oversleep.

Answer (score -1):

Its annoying to lower the volume especially if you have max volume cause its like the other end of the earth and takes forever. Hence the point of having a button.

No, such an app is not available as of date. =(

WP7 User.